# Postgres/PostGIS find if line intersects circle?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am having trouble figuring this out, I have 2 points A & B, I need to draw a straight line, and then see if this line intersects with circle C

What is the best way to do this? (I am new to Postgres so details would be super appreciated), steps to do:

- draw line from A to B
- see if line L intersects circle C of radius R

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`ST_MakeLine`](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.5/ST_MakeLine.html) to create a line from two points and [`ST_Intersects`](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.5/ST_Intersects.html) to see if it intersects with the circle.

But it is probably easier to use the [`<->`](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.5/geometry_distance_knn.html) distance operator to see if the distance of the line from the center is less than the radius.